# SWI-Prolog Installation on RHEL 7

Tags: prolog, redhat, rhel, swi-prolog

I am attempting to install SWI-Prolog on a server running rhel 7.

I have followed the instructions to build SWI-Prolog here: http://www.swi-prolog.org/build/Redhat.html. The build completes without error; however, I see no trace of the application.

In addition, the application does not seem accessible because I am unable to invoke swipl to begin executing Prolog commands.

Comment: After following the instructions, you must install the package. Does the following work for you: `sudo yum install RPMS/x86_64/pl-*.rpm`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Fedora 24, so probably close to your RHEL 7 situation.  I never build the RPM, I simply build from sources:

```
git clone https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel
cd swipl-devel
cp build.tmpl build
<EDITOR> build <TO CUSTOMIZE>
./build
```

In the customization step you can set a specific directory on your system.  That way you're 100% sure where it ends up.

Comment: Your instructions worked fine with the downloaded sources (tgz) from [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/stable) - but not with cloned git.

Comment: Yes, the above instructions no longer apply to recent versions of SWI-Prolog, which now uses CMake i.o. Make.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [SWIPL build instructions](http://www.swi-prolog.org/build/unix.html) on my CentOS 7.6.1810.
I faced two issues when configuring using cmake as per instructions

> cmake ..

First, I had to install cmake3

> yum install cmake3

and had to invoke it thus:

> cmake3 ..

Secondly, cmake had trouble setting X11_Xpm_LIB. So I manually set the line in CMakeCache.txt

> X11_Xpm_LIB:FILEPATH=/usr/lib64/libXpm.so.4

After this the config process completed successfully.
But my build is failing :(

Comment: Can you try the following? `cd build` then `cmake -G Ninja ..` then `ninja` then `sudo ninja install`?  (<-- Sorry, newlines are not allowed in SO comments it seems.)